# Trying to run rails server but it is looking for a deprecated gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In command prompt I run

**rails server**

and it gives me the error: "could not find nokogiri -1.10.0 in any of the sources"

I then go to install the gem:

**gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.0**

and git gives me the error: "The last version of nokogiri (=1.10.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.10.0. nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, < 2.7.dev. The current version is 2.7.2.137

How do I get around this issue?

Also, I'm sure I'm going to run into a similar problem again every time I try to run

**rails server**

It keeps telling me there is a missing gem which tells me me there is something wrong with the install. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Ruby multiple times but the issue doesn't get resolved. Help with my first question would be great but help with my overarching issue would be even more appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm running version 2.7.2.137. I understand that that is not in the range that the error gave me (>=2.3, <2.7 dev). I could downgrade as @spickermann said but I agree with him that I would prefer to upgrade nokogiri instead of downgrading Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Nokogiri you try to install is not compatible with the latest version of Ruby. You have two options:

1. Downgrade Ruby to `<= 2.6.6` or
2. Upgrade Nokogiri to `>= 1.10.4`

It depends on your application which option to choose.

I would prefer upgrading Nokogiri to the latest version. To do so change the version of Nokogiri in your `Gemfile` to `1.10.10` and run

```
$ gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.10
$ bundle update nokogiri
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clear in the original question. I have tried to install the up-to-date version of nokogiri 1.10.10 but when I try to run the rails server it still says that version 1.10.0 is missing

Comment: Did you update the Nokogiri version in your `Gemfile` (if there is any number) and did you run `bundle update nokogiri` after `gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.10`?

Comment: in my __Gemfile__ there is no version number it just says: gem 'nokogiri', require: false. I'm not sure how to update the nokogiri version. I have tried __bundle update nokogiri__ after __gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.10__ but it says "could not find gem 'ruby (<2.6, >= 2.0)', which is required by gem 'pg', in any of the relevant sources: the local ruby installation"

Comment: Seems like the `pg` gem version that is bundled with your app is not compatible with Ruby 2.7 too. `pg` supports Ruby 2.7 since 1.2.0. Perhaps it is easier for you to downgrade to Ruby 2.6.6 and start updating your app from there.

Comment: Another option might be to simply try to update all gems at once by running `bundle update` without any specific gem name. Totally depends on your application and how old it is if that works or not. Without proper tests, I would not try that.

Comment: so i have downgraded to v 2.6.6 and that solved the nokogiri issue but now it's just asking me to install missing gem after missing gem. I have no idea how many more I have to install. Is there a way to know how many are left? If by "without proper tests" you mean that it could have negative effects on my app, I'm not concerned about that as I didn't write it and I can just delete it and just unzip it again. Should I try the __bundle update__?

Comment: Calling `bundle install` should install all gems (in the version that is defined in the `Gemfile.lock` if it exists)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226001/discussion-between-user2382321-and-spickermann).

Comment: helped me. Looks like I was trying to install a very old app that required me to downgrade even further to 2.5.8. Thanks for your help